# Time-domain model of a capacitor when the capacitance is varying with time

Tags: capacitance, gauss-law

The current through a capacitor as a function of time is given by;

$$i(t)=C\cdot \frac{d}{dt}U(t)$$

When assuming that the capacitance $C$ does not vary with time.

**But what if it does?**

I don't know how to derive the equation above from Gauss's law, so here is instead my attempt at a "common-sense" kind of solution, I don't know whether this is valid or nonsense.

Integrating the equation above;

$$Q(t)=\int i(t) dt=C\cdot U(t)$$

..we get the equation for charge $Q=C\cdot U$,

I assume that this is always valid, even if $C$ is a function of time (let's ignore relativity and quantum mechanics for a moment).

If that is true then to get back to the original equation all I need to do is differentiate, this time letting $C$ be a function of time;

$$i(t)=\frac{d}{dt}Q(t)=\frac{d}{dt}[C(t)\cdot U(t)]=\frac{d}{dt}C(t)\cdot U(t)+C(t)\cdot \frac{d}{dt}U(t)$$

..which gives the result;

$$i(t)=\frac{d}{dt}C(t)\cdot U(t)+C(t)\cdot \frac{d}{dt}U(t)$$

**Is this equation valid? Or how do you solve for the current through a capacitor with varying capacitance and voltage?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation correctly expresses the charge as an integral of the current:
$$Q(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}i(\tau)d\tau.$$
The problem however is with the definition of capacitance, used in the second equation, as a proportionality coefficient between the charge and the potential difference, $Q(t)=C(t)U(t)$, since *there is no reason to think that charge instantaneously responds to a change in the potential!* In fact, for this to be true we would need to have infinite current, which would make meaningless the first equation.

The closest working solution to defining linear capacitance is relating the charge and the potential via a convolution integral:
$$Q(t) = \int_{-\infty}^tC(t-\tau)U(\tau).$$
While this may appear as a complication, it is in fact a simplification from the point of view of the circuit theory, since in the frequency domain (i.e., after the Laplace or Fourier transform) we would get
$$\tilde{Q}(\omega)=\tilde{C}(\omega)\tilde{U}(\omega),$$
i.e. convenient linear relation.

**Update**
While the discussion above focused on the incompatibility between the expressions relating charge&current and charge&potential in the question, it missed the essential point - that the capacitance is changing in time. This means that we need to use $C(t,\tau)$ rather than $C(t -\tau)$, which further complicates the issue.

Comment: Assuming an ideal capacitor, no inductance or resistance, isn't it the case that if I was to instantaniously change the potential then the charge would also have to change instantaniously, ie. The current would in fact be infinite (which hence of course would be impossible). Im confused?

Comment: this not how a varactor works, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicap, a varactor (back-biased diode) is a time varying capacitor whose capacitance is controlled by a separate external voltage.

Comment: @Vinzent One can always make the capacitor charge instantaneously by taking $C(t-\tau)=C\times\delta(t-\tau)$. But it means that we bring instantaneously an infinite charge to the capacitor, i.e. the current is infinite, and expressing the charge as in integral of the current doesn't make sense.

Comment: @hyportnex not sure what your comment refers to, but I certainly made an omission, since my capacitance depends only on the difference of times. For time-dependent capacitance one should take $C(t, \tau)$.

Comment: you seem to have dismissed the formula $Q(t)=C(t)V(t)$ as not being valid but in fact it is at the basis of all tunable radio circuits where $C=C(t) =f (V_1(t))$ and $v(t)$ is small RF signal, so that $q(t)=C(t)v(t)$ while $|v|<<V_1$ so the diode is always backbiased and $V_1(t)$ is the *slowly* time varying back bias voltage.

Comment: @hyportnex it is slowly varying and therefore effectively treated as static. This is a valid approximation, but not the general case. But I appreciate your comment - I think it adds value here.

Comment: @Vadim it adds a lot of value for me to know that my original solution is valid in the speciale case that hyportnex is describing.. A side question related to the note on laplace transformation at the end of your answer; does that also mean that the impedance of the varying capacitance in the laplace domain is simpely Z(s) =1/(C(s) *s)???

Comment: @Vinzent I added an update, since there was actually a problem with my initial answer: it took into account the finite charging time, but not the time varying capacitance. With time variation the Laplace transform won't work.

Comment: @Vadim Ok, I actually need to transform it to the s domain so how do I then go about that? My situation happens to match the one described by hyportnex, but of course a more general solution would be more interresting :).. I can be a bit more precise: I have two moving parallel plates with a Bias voltage across them which is not varying, the change in voltage caused by this is small compared to the Bias potential. The change in capacitance is also small compared to the absolute capacitance.. (we are Talking about a capacitive microphone)

Comment: The slow variation is a practical/application requirement for *tunable* circuit. In general, the "smallness" of $v$ is more important as the diode's charge depends on the total voltage $Q(v+V_1) \approx Q(V_1)+(dQ/dv) v$. and then $q(t) \approx (dQ/dv) v = f(V_1) v$ and $c=f(V_1)$ is the differential capacitance. If you vary $V_1$ "fast" you can get parametric amplification of the signal $v(t)$, this is rarely if ever used nowadays, but was a dominant technology 50 years ago...

Answer (score 1):

Yes your equation for i(t) is right

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will accept it if no better answers are given. Specifically I would like to see just a bit of rationale behind the answer.

Comment: but you gave the rational behind it yourself with Q=C(t)*U(t) and dQ/dt=i

Comment: okay but then you could at least add to the answer that the reason it is correct is that my rationale is correct ;). I can't read from your answer whether you came to that conclusion by following your own different line of thinking, or added some knowledge/insight that I don't have..

Comment: sorry not mentioning your reasoning, you should be more confident of your arguments.